# How to call web api post method in asp.net with multiple arguments

Tags: c#, post, asp.net-web-api

I am writing a simple Web API application. I am writing a post method to add records like this:

```
[Route("api/{Inspection}/{post}/{date}/{inspectorId}/{unitID}/{time}")]
[HttpPost]
public void PostInspection(string date,int inspectorId,int unitID,string time)
{
    InspectionDataClass inspectionData = new InspectionDataClass();
    inspectionData.InsertRow(date,inspectorId,unitID,false,false,"", time);
}
```

and call the method in browser like this:

```
http://localhost:34367/api/inspection/97/3/13/10
```

but it doesn't execute.

Answer (score 1):

Your  attribute :

```
[Route("api/{Inspection}/{post}/{date}/{inspectorId}/{unitID}/{time}")]
```

But you browser url with:

```
http://localhost:34367/api/inspection/97/3/13/10
```

Did you have miss the path for /{post}/?

And sorry for my last wrong anser and my pool English.I thought you  have using asp.net core.

Comment: thank you for your response but I get new error:" HttpPostAttribute' does not contain a constructor that takes 1 arguments" I use visual studio 2015 ...

Comment: I'm sorry for i make a mistake,your attribute with Rout is [Route("api/{Inspection}/{post}/{date}/{inspectorId}/{unitID}/{time}")]   and the 
path whith {post}  do not  contain in your browser url:http://localhost:34367/api/inspection/97/3/13/10

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, and your guide. I change url to " http://localhost:34367/api/inspection/post/97/3/13/10" but I see this message in browser : " "Message": "The requested resource does not support http method 'GET'." "  Do you know this Reason?

Comment: Becuse you use browser,They use HttpGet.You can download Postman https://www.getpostman.com/  and use  post method to  test your api

Comment: my problem is solving with your help ..Thank you very much

Comment: @jalalhojati if this solved your problem you could "accept" it by clicking the checkmark on the left hand side.